# Declaration and definition of union

Tags: c, types, structure, unions

Why does this code work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 union var{
 int a, b, c;
 };
 printf("%ld", sizeof(union var));
 return 0;
}
```

My doubt is that isn't union var a declaration only, and during declaration no memory is allocated. So why does this code print 4?

Comment: You are asking the code to print the size of the *type.* You can do the same with `int`, without actually declaring an `int` variable.

Comment: and you should be using the `%z` (probably `%zu`) format specifier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-can-one-print-a-size-t-variable-portably-using-the-printf-family

Comment: @Beta Does a union or structure declaration have memory associated with it?

Comment: My doubt is regarding declaration and definition @Beta

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584541/does-structure-declaration-occupies-memory

Comment: Yes, it does. What are you unsure of?

Answer (score 3):

It prints 4 because that's how big a `union var` variable is. The fact that there are no `union var` variables in your program, is completely irrelevant. If you created one, for example by writing `union var myUnionVar;`, it would use 4 bytes of memory

You can also do this with structs:

```
struct list_node {
    struct list_node *next;
    int key;
    int value;
};

// note that sizeof returns a size_t which should be printed with %zu
printf("%zu", sizeof(struct list_node)); // prints 12 or 16, probably
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate " It prints 4 because that's how big a union var variable is."

Comment: @programmer Do you know what variables are and what structs are? And how unions are kinda like structs but not really?

Comment: Though I  know the differences between structures and union, I don't see how it is relevant to this question. Anyways, please tell what particular difference you want me to know

Comment: @programmer Do you know what an int variable is?

Comment: @programmer _how big a variable variable is_ = _the size a variable uses in memory_. An `int` typically uses 4 bytes.

Comment: Ah I got it now, union is a user defined data type just like int.. So it would print how many bytes would be occupied by a variable of that type if a variable of that type would be declared, right?

Comment: @programmer Yes.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` is an operator that yields the size in bytes of its argument (right-hand-side operand). The operand can either be a type or a variable. Most of the time, the result is a constant that can be evaluated at compile time.

`union var` is a type, therefore with `sizeof(union var)` you are asking "what size would occupy a variable if it had the type `union var`?" The answer is 4 bytes.